# merge 2 indicators on one chart qqe

Tags: pine-script

I struggle to merge 2 indicators qqe mod and Waddah Attar Explosion. i've got so many errors. the both indicators were directly forcked from original source. can somebody help me to fix the errors

here is the complete [indicators source code](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hVf6ItyvBLacxor3qoYpqEkBfB_5U_AgisA7pD5qkns/edit?usp=sharing)

```
plot(trendUp, style=columns, linewidth=1, color=(trendUp<trendUp[1])?lime:green, transp=45, title="UpTrend")
plot(trendDown, style=columns, linewidth=1, color=(trendDown<trendDown[1])?orange:red, transp=45, title="DownTrend")
plot(e1, style=line, linewidth=2, color=#A0522D, title="ExplosionLine")
plot(DEAD_ZONE, color=blue, linewidth=1, style=cross, title="DeadZoneLine")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

QQE Mod is v4 and Waddah Attar Explosion is v1. You need to upgrade the Waddah indicator to at least v4 bz using [this](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/index.html#) migration guidelines.